# Google PubSub Library does not publish messages on a topic but does not throw any error

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub, publisher

My publishing service is as follows:

```
public class PubGoogleService {

private static final String TOPIC_ID = "topictest";

private static final String PROJECT_ID = ServiceOptions.getDefaultProjectId();

@Inject
ObjectMapper objectMapper;

private Publisher publisher;

@PostConstruct
private void postConstruct() {
    log.info("----------------------------------" + "postConstruct()");
    AppIdentityService appIdentityService = AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService();
    GoogleCredentials credentials = AppEngineCredentials.newBuilder().setAppIdentityService(appIdentityService).build();
    log.info("----------------------------------" + " projectId=" + PROJECT_ID);
    ProjectTopicName topicName = ProjectTopicName.newBuilder()
            .setProject(PROJECT_ID)
            .setTopic(TOPIC_ID)
            .build();
    publisher = null;
    try {
        publisher = Publisher
                .newBuilder(topicName)
                .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
                .build();
        log.info("----------------------------------" + "Created publisher!!!!");
        log.info("----------------------------------" + publisher.getTopicNameString());
        log.info("----------------------------------" + credentials.toString());
        log.info("----------------------------------" + appIdentityService.getServiceAccountName());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.info("It was not possible to create the Pub / Sub publisher of Google.");
        log.warning(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void publish(String message) {
    try {
        log.info("----------------------------------" + "publish()");
        PubsubMessage pubsubMessage = PubsubMessage.newBuilder().setData(ByteString.copyFromUtf8(message)).build();
        log.info("----------------------------------" + pubsubMessage.toString());
        ApiFuture<String> future = publisher.publish(pubsubMessage);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.info("----------------------------------" + "e.toString()");
        log.info(e.toString());
        log.info("----------------------------------" + "e.getMessage()");
        log.info(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**I have given Pub / Sub administrator permissions to my service account in GCP.**

**The library version is:** google-cloud-pubsub 1.100

**The GCP log is:**

[Logs GCP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1WvF.png)

**The problem is that it does not generate any errors. The message is never published in PubSub. What I can be doing wrong ?**

Comment: how do you check that no message is published?

Comment: Because in the GCP web console, I create a subscription for that topic and the messages don't appear to me.

Comment: Did you create the subscription before or after your test? Did you create a pull subscription or a push subscription?

Comment: I create the subscription before. In fact, the subscription is created through the web console as well. The subscription is of the pull type.

Comment: Can you try to wait the end of the `future`? add this line after the publish `log.info("----------------------------------" + future.get());`

Comment: Yes, the result is "null"

Comment: improved code formatting.

Comment: Just right away your program finish, and before running your validation program, what is the result of `gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull projects/YOUR_PROJECT/subscriptions/YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION` ?

Comment: I am having a same issue right now, If you run same code using main method than it will works, only having issue while call with post construct and webservice call

Comment: I'm having the same issue but with the Nodejs client, did you manage to find out what's the cause of this ?